# Salesforce Lightning Tab URL not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am working on an assignment where the phone number of a contact will be passed via the URL. I have developed a lightning tab, associated with a Lightning component with the corresponding js controller, helper and apex controller and the functionality is working fine from the development sandbox where I have developed. Now, I deployed the components to the QA sandbox and when I try the QA URL (exactly in the same format as the DEV URL), I am getting a "Page doesn't exist" error. A screenshot is given below.

[image: Lightning tab URL Issue]

The DEV URL is below.
https://dtc--dtcDEV.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/n/RPCMemberSearch?phoneNumber=6232241123

The QA URL is below.
https://dtc--dtcQA.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/n/RPCMemberSearch?phoneNumber=6232241123

RPCMemberSearch is the lightning tab associated with the lightning component RPCMemberSearch.cmp. The DEV URL parses the phone number, queries salesforce, and lists the contacts if there are multiple contacts. If there is a single contact, the contact page will be displayed. If there are no contacts associated with the supplied phone number, a message will be displayed accordingly and "Goto Home" button will be available. All this works fine in DEV, but not in QA. Can some one help? I am not sure if this is related to Summer 18 release that was pushed by Salesforce over the weekend.

FYI, I have not developed a separate app for this.

Comment: I seem to remember that was something... oh that's right, we've been bombarded with warnings that the url format has changed. Maybe you should check your url format.

Comment: I tried both old and new URLs and I still get the same error message. In sandboxes, when we enter the old URLs, it is automatically getting changed to new URL anyway.

Comment: Kinda hard to provide feedback without seeing any code

Answer (score 2):

I figured the issue. I have deployed the lightning components, tab and apex controller to the QA sandbox without the profiles. I did manually set the permissions for the Apex controller. I was not aware that I need to explicitly set the permissions for the lightning tab under the object settings for the related profiles. Once I set the permissions for the lightning tab, the component started working fine.

Comment: It helped a lot..!! :)